# Sending notification to other Android devices witnin particular range

Tags: android, gps, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been doing some research about sending notification from one device to another.

I came across [GSM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/tutorial/data-push.html). But how can I send notification to devices within 5km range who are using my app?

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to have a service in your app that tracks the location of the device and transmits this location periodically to your server. The app will also, of course, register to GCM. Your server will maintain a table with the current location for each GCM Registration ID.

Then, when you wish to send GCM messages to devices within a certain range of some location, your server will know which devices to send the messages to.

Comment: I initially thought of this. It could be implemented for less number of devices. but what if there are 1000's of ppl using the app?